# Coffee not working on Zappa install (Mac OSX 10.9)

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, zappa

I'm following the `zappa` guide here: http://zappajs.github.io/zappajs/docs/crashcourse, but I can't seem to get `coffee` to work - on Mac OSX 10.9 - as demonstrated into the guide. If I type:

```
coffee cuppa.coffee
```

I get:

```
-bash: coffee: command not found
```

I installed `zappa` with the following command:

```
sudo npm install zappa -g
```

Now, it's likely this is a paths issue, but I can not determine where `npm` installed `coffee` to. Other SO questions suggest it's stored under `/usr/local/share/npm/coffee` but it's not. I can find the `npm` directory under `/usr/local/bin/npm` but `coffee` isn't there.

Any suggestions to setting it up so it works correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll likely want to install CoffeeScript by itself:

```
sudo npm install coffee-script -g
```

This will give you the `coffee` command.

Comment: When I installed `zappa` it appears it installed the dependancy already though: npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script

Comment: True; you could add `coffee` to your path inside of Zappa's `node_modules` directory. I'd recommend installing CoffeeScript independently, though.

Comment: Installed independently and it worked. I'll settle with this answer. Thank you.